# Java - Japplet can not changebackground color

Tags: java, netbeans, japplet

I am unable to change the background color of my JApplet. It is always gray color. I am working in NetBeans. Anyone have any suggestions? Thank you.

**Solution** Thanks to Крысa's answer the following is the solution to the problem: must use getContentPane().setBackground(Color.WHITE);

```
@Override
public void init() {

    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //Look and feel setting code (optional)

    /* Create and display the applet */
    try {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                getContentPane().setBackground(Color.WHITE);
                initComponents();
            }
        });
    } catch (Exception ex) {}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the background of the `JApplet`'s *content pane*.

Comment: Thank you very very very much. I figured it out now thanks to your answer.

getContentPane().setBackground(Color.WHITE);

and this is supposed to be inside of: public void init()
of the JApplet